# jQuery on API doesn't bind automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe I misunderstood the functions of [`.on()` api of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Here is the code I am trying out:

http://jsfiddle.net/tugberk/Um9VE/

```
<a class="btn" href="#">foo</a>
<a href="#" class="new">New</a>

<script>
    $(function(){ 
        $("a.btn").on("click", function(){ 
            alert("foo");
        });
        $("a.new").click(function(){
            $("html").append($("<a/>").attr("class", "btn").attr("href", "#").text("bar"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I create a new `a.btn` element, the event is not auto-attached after the element is being created. I can achieve this with [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) api easily by triggering it after I create the new button but one of my friends suggested me that .on() event is doing this automatically.

So, did I misunderstand the capabilities of `.on()` api?

Comment: You can achieve this using .live() - I think .on() can only be used with already existing elements

Comment: @MonkeyCoder look at my answer below. .on() handles all the variants of bind, live and delegate

Comment: @MonkeyCoder live has been deprecated.

Comment: @Jasper +1 for you - that's something that I was missing ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `.on()` to work like `.delegate()` or `.live()` it requires a special syntax. The different kinds of ways you can use `.on()`/`.off()` are shown below, together with the old ways of doing it with `.bind()`/`.live()` and `.delegate()`, along with `.undelegate()` and `.die()`.

```
$('a').bind('click', myHandler);
$('a').on('click', myHandler);

$('form').bind('submit', { val: 42 }, fn);
$('form').on('submit', { val: 42 }, fn);

$(window).unbind('scroll.myPlugin');
$(window).off('scroll.myPlugin');

$('.comment').delegate('a.add', 'click', addNew);
$('.comment').on('click', 'a.add', addNew);

$('.dialog').undelegate('a', 'click.myDlg');
$('.dialog').off('click.myDlg', 'a');

$('a').live('click', fn);
$(document).on('click', 'a', fn);

$('a').die('click');
$(document).off('click', 'a');
```

Comment: Great! I'd appreciate it if you marked it as an actual answer too ;)

Comment: I cannot, it won't allow me :) A certain time needs to pass:)